# How to apply a concat function to a group by data frame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code 1:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['d'])
df2 = df.set_index(['d', 'c'])
df3 = df2.groupby(level=['c'])

def function(x):
    a = pd.rolling_mean(x, 3).rename(columns = {'b':'rm'})
    c = pd.rolling_std(x, 3).rename(columns = {'b':'rsd'})
    pd.concat([x, a, c], axis=1)

df4 = df3.apply(lambda x: function(x))
```

Code 2:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['d'])
df2 = df.set_index(['d', 'c'])
df3 = df2.groupby(level=['c'])

def function(x):
    x.assign(rm = lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, 3))

df4 = df3.apply(lambda x: function(x))
```

Output of df4.head() in both of the above code1 AND code 2 is a square in iPython?? I can't figure out why.

Output:

[image]

What df3 looks like:

[image]

What df looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you try - `x = pd.concat([x, a, c], axis=1)` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Same error!

Comment: what error? Are you using `df.plot()` to get that square? Can you show example of your dataframe.

Comment: Sorry no error, just the same square. No I am not using df.plot. I try just df4 or df4.head and get the square as my output.

Comment: Can you show example data in your df?

Comment: I added an image above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you simply print the `df` into the terminal in ipython and then copy the data (rather than the image) , that way i can directly copy it and use `pd.read_clipboard()` to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92675/discussion-between-pr338-and-anand-s-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a return statement:

```
In [11]: def function(x):
             a = pd.rolling_mean(x, 3).rename(columns = {'bookings':'rm'})
             c = pd.rolling_std(x, 3).rename(columns = {'bookings':'rsd'})
             return pd.concat([x, a, c], axis=1)

In [12]: df3.apply(lambda x: function(x))
Out[12]:
                   bookings          rm        rsd
ds         city
2013-01-01 City_2        69         NaN        NaN
2013-01-02 City_2       101         NaN        NaN
2013-01-03 City_2       134  101.333333  32.501282
2013-01-04 City_2       155  130.000000  27.221315
2013-01-05 City_2       104  131.000000  25.632011
2013-01-06 City_2       121  126.666667  25.967929
2013-01-07 City_2       143  122.666667  19.553346
2013-01-08 City_2       173  145.666667  26.102363
2013-01-09 City_2       142  152.666667  17.616280
2013-01-10 City_2       154  156.333333  15.631165
2013-01-11 City_2       139  145.000000   7.937254
```

Without the return `function` was returning None, hence the empty DataFrame (which was rendered by ipython as a square - which may be a bug).

```
In [13]: df3.apply(lambda x: None)
Out[13]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

Note: In some languages (e.g. Ruby, Julia, Scala) the last line is returned without being explicit with the return. In Python if you miss out the return statement the function returns None.

```
In [21]: def foo():
             1

In [22]: foo() == None
Out[22]: True
```